# PHP Blacklist words in String

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a piece of Javascript code that generates a dynamic XML string. This XML string is then passed to a PHP file where I need to check to make sure the string doesn't contain any bad words that could allow for SQL injection.

I figured I would just create a blacklist and if any word was found, we just don't send the XML to the database.

My snippet of code however isn't returning true when I pass in one or more of the blacklist words.

```
// Create a blacklist array
$blacklist = Array('create', 'alter', 'update', 'delete', 'drop', 'insert', 'into', 'from', 'where');

// Define our vars
$xml = '<blah>alert table drop something create</blah>';
$actor = $_COOKIE['QID'];
$sp = $_POST['sp'];

// Lets check the XML string to see if it contains any database altering words
function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($a,$str) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Check our XML string
if(contains($xml, $blacklist))
{
    echo 'Contains';
}
else
{
    echo 'Does not contain';
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this type of check? I wasn't sure what to search for so figured the blacklist of words would be sufficient.

Comment: You should be less worried about words in the string and more worried about quotes in it. None of those words will cause a problem as long as they are properly quoted.

Comment: the xml is being used in a dynamic SQL query. The xml contains field names that the user wants to include in their report. When the query runs, it creates a select statement using each of the values in the XML string as the field names. I would rather just not allow those words to make it past this function at all, there is no need for them to exist in the string that's being created.

Comment: Could you show more of your code then? Including the part that generates and executes any queries? Using parameterized queries will likely provide the protection you need. If you really want to use the blacklist approach, you're going to need a much bigger list.

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickQ - That code is so long and probably over complicated to share. I was mostly trying to figure out why the above code wouldn't return true in my example when it contains the words in the array. I have no problem populating a list. This is an internal site, just trying to prevent the curious people from any damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameters in the wrong order when calling [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).  Instead of `stripos($a,$str)`, you want `stripos($str,$a)`.  The first version is search for the entire XML string within an individual "bad" word.  The second searches for the word within the XML string.